# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment

Tags: ubuntu

I open a terminal and use `sudo -s -u mysql`. Now when i try to open a file, whose owner is `mysql` using `gedit xyz.err`, I get the error :

```
No protocol specified

** (gedit:23076): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gedit:23076): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Is there some way to resolve this error ?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the fact that mysql is a system account as opposed to being a user account.

Comment: I think it is related to the way is mounted your Drive
Are you trying to execute it from an other partition? I got a very similar error and as far as I can tell is about the other drive (in my case) is not mounted with executable permission.
Still investigating, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: XDG\_RUNTIME\_DIR not set in the environment. Gtk-WARNING \*\*: cannot open display:](http://superuser.com/questions/987993/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-gtk-warning-cannot-open-d)

Comment: See also [difference between `sudo` and `gksudo`](/q/202676/150988) and [Open a new terminal window on another user session](/q/539928/150988), and maybe also [Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display](/q/898277/150988) and [Gtk-WARNING with display when using `sudo` in nx](/q/434368/150988).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an interactive session by using `su - mysql`, and then run `gedit`. Works for me.

`man sudo` doesn't give any details, but it could be that the default shell launched with `-s` is very limited.

Comment: my intention is a bit different. I want to keep a terminal open that uses the mysql account previliges. That is why i use the "sudo -s -u mysql". So that any further commands don't require me to use sudo. Using gksudo to open gedit every time does not really serve my purpose.

Comment: Using "su - mysql" and then gedit, as suggested in your edited answer, also gives me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking in the wrong place, running mysql as (system) user mysql won't solve anything.

`mysql` is a client program, the authentication to the server, run by `mysqld`, is made on the connection (tcpdump port 3306 to make it clear).

Therefore, you can launch mysql with any "system" user, like:

```
$ mysql -u root -p localhost
```

Give the admin ("root") password when prompted, and then you should see this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 240
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

...and there you go!

Comment: Sorry for the misleading OP, but it has nothing to do with the `mysql` program. It is to do with opening a file in `gedit` with a particular account, which happens to be `mysql`.