# error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment. Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: sudo, sublime-text-2, ubuntu-14.04, gtk, gksudo

I used to open text files with sublime, and for Read-only files, I used to do :
`sudo sublime`. But now just suddenly the `sudo sublime` command gives the following error :

```
(sublime:3931): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

while `sublime` command is working fine. I tried the same with `gedit`, and the same thing happened, with the error with gedit being shown :

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
(gedit:3933): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I installed `gtk`, and tried `gksudo`, still got the same error!

I searched the web and found these ways :

1. `xhost +localhost` : https://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0
2. `export DISPLAY=:0.0` :
3. `ssh username@hostname -X`
4. `ssh username@hostname -Y`
5. [How do I fix a "cannot open display" error when opening an X program after ssh'ing with X11 forwarding enabled?](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi)

None of the above worked.

**What worked out for me was :**

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sublime
```

From here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/456689/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-when-attempting-to-run-naut

I want to know why exactly am I getting this error, that too suddenly! Also, I want to get back to the `sudo sublime` version, since it is easy to remember. How can I fix that?

Also, the recent changes I did to the system were :

1. Installed Mac theme for Ubuntu : http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html
2. Installed gksu(for gksudo)

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo env DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY" sublime`? (In any case, you should always quote all shell variables references unless you have a good reason not to.)

Answer (score 0):

Any system updates lately...
[This](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794972) sounds related.  Maybe [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam-xdg-support/+bug/894391)

If you have something that works, you can always just put it in a shell script and keep that script in your path.
In Debian you can create a 'bin' directory in your home folder and that will automatically be included in your path; I'm not certain if it works on Ubuntu, but chances are good.

So in ~/bin create 'sublime-root.sh' and put your pkexec stuff in there?